# shared album using google photos API for server to server

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-photos-api

i'm trying to build simple service to retrieve photos or access a shared album using google phots API , node.js and service account credentials.
this is the code i'm using -

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'];

// Load the service account key
import key from './servicekeyoauth.json' assert { type: 'json' };

// Create an OAuth2 client
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: key.client_email,
    key: key.private_key,
    scopes: SCOPES,
});

// Initialize the Photos Library API client
const photosLibrary = google.photoslibrary({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: authClient,
});

async function getPhotosFromSharedAlbum() {
    try {
        // Authenticate with the OAuth2 client
        await authClient.authorize();

        // Replace 'sharedAlbumId' with your shared album ID
        const sharedAlbumId = 'ALBUM_ID';

        // List the media items (photos) from the shared album
        const response = await photosLibrary.mediaItems.search({
            albumId: sharedAlbumId,
        });

        const mediaItems = response.data.mediaItems;

        // Process the media items (photos)
        console.log('Media Items:');
        mediaItems.forEach((mediaItem, index) => {
            console.log(`Photo ${index + 1}:`);
            console.log(`Title: ${mediaItem.filename}`);
            console.log(`Media URL: ${mediaItem.baseUrl}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
}

// Call the function to retrieve photos from the shared album
getPhotosFromSharedAlbum();
```

i'm getting the error - google.photoslibrary is not a function

i changed the code to - **new** google.photoslibrary({
but got this error - google.photoslibrary is not a constructor

any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Where did you find `photoslibrary` of `google.photoslibrary`? When I checked googleapis@126.0.1 (latest version), unfortunately, `google` has no property of `photoslibrary`. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. But, from your showing script, I thought that you might know the method for using `google.photoslibrary`. So, I asked about it.

Comment: i got it from AI but maybe you are correct, how i suppose to change the code so it will be correct?

Comment: Hi all, i dont undestand what is wrong, i got access token via the hosted UI in the user Cognito, i'm using this access token in my lambda function but keep getting the error -> Failed to access Google Photos API. Status Code: 401 -> can someone point what i'm missing here? i change my code to python language as i see it suppose to be more simplified